# Automapper map list of object to another object in different list of objects, nested mapping

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper, mapper

public class First
{

```
public List<ClassA> AList{ get; set; }
```

}

public class ClassA
{

```
public string FirstName{ get; set; }

public string LastName{ get; set; }
```

}

public class Second
{

```
public List<ClassB> BList{ get; set; }
```

}

public class ClassB
{

```
public ClassC Cobj { get; set; }

public string Email { get; set; }
```

}

public class ClassC
{

```
public string FirstName{ get; set; }

public string LastName{ get; set; }
```

}

unable to get results for converting ClassA to ClassC, while trying to map **First and Second**

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Reverse Mapping and Unflattening](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html) could help

```csharp
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<First, Second>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.BList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AList));
    cfg.CreateMap<ClassB, ClassA>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cobj.FirstName))
       .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Cobj.LastName))
       .ReverseMap();
});
```